# What is 'list' variable type in php?

Tags: php, google-fusion-tables, google-api-php-client

I`m trying to use google php api client, exactly fusiontables. For creating table parameters setting this way:

```
$postBody = new Google_Service_Fusiontables_Table;
$postBody->setName('Test');
```

I also should set at least one column this way

```
$postBody->setColumns($columns);
```

But documentation says $columns should have 'list' value. What does it mean?
[here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpFqB.jpg)
String and boolean is very clear, but what is list?

According to Google`s documentation, it`s request body. What the syntax? What does mean braces and how can I set $columns? [request body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSNCB.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure you are reading the PHP documentation

Comment: No, but there`s no PHP documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list of columns here is of type **array** . A column requires at least these properties:

1. the `name` of the column
2. the `type` of the column ("DATETIME","LOCATION","NUMBER" or "STRING")

When you use the **google php api client** a column is expected to be an instance of `Google_Service_Fusiontables_Column`

You may set the required properties directly by passing them via an array to the constructor:

```
new Google_Service_Fusiontables_Column(array('type'=>'STRING','name'=>'desiredColumName'));
```

A complete creation of a table (with 2 columns) would look like this:

```
//create FusionTable-instance
$table = new Google_Service_Fusiontables_Table;

//set table-name
$table->setName('myTableName');

//set required option isExportable
$table->setIsExportable('true');

//set column(s)
$table->setColumns(array(
                          new Google_Service_Fusiontables_Column(array('type'=>'STRING',
                                                                       'name'=>'columnName')),
                          new Google_Service_Fusiontables_Column(array('type'=>'NUMBER',
                                                                       'name'=>'otherName'))
                        )
                  );

//insert the table
//$service is a Google_Service_Fusiontables-instance
$result = $service->table->insert($table);

//display Id of the new FusionTable
echo $result->tableId;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is just an array of strings.  List is not a PHP datatype although there is an unrelated function called [list()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php).

Comment: Array doesn`t fit, it give`s an error. I`ve also tried json encode.

Comment: What field? $columns is emty, I should set it

Comment: I don't know enough about the Fusiontables API you're using to answer that.  Maybe someone can add to this answer.

Comment: How would you made that array, considering braces?